# finding a particular data-id in a parent container using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say if I have the following html:

```
<a href="some url" class="product-store-name">
    azzaharastore
</a>
```

and this html is contained inside another div, and another div, of x levels. Is there a way to find the div that has the data-id in it and then get the value of it? In other words I want a function that propates upwards and find the data-id in it.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more.? Provide some detailed markup too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) along with [has attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) to find the desired element

if `this` refers to this element then use(replace `this` with any other means to refer the target element)

```
var $div = $(this).closest('div[data-id]'); 
var did = $div.data('id');
```

or for the above said case

```
var did  = $('.product-store-name').closest('div[data-id]').data('id')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wjJwY/)